# Which pronoun do I need to shorten “pour cette agence de voyage”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> Depuis combien de temps travailles-tu pour cette agence de voyages?

If I want to replace *cette agence de voyages* by a pronoun, which one do I want?

Would it be this?

> J'y travaille depuis dix ans.

Seems right and wrong but I can't think of a better one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you’re actually one of their employee (not a freelancer who often works for them), you could say either “*J’y travaille depuis dix ans*“ (which who be short for “*Je travaille dans cette agence de voyage depuis dix ans*”)  or “*Je travaille pour eux depuis dix ans*“ (i.e. “*Je travaille pour mes employeurs depuis dix ans*“).

If you’re actually a freelancer who works for them, but not one of their employee, I would use “*Je travaille pour eux depuis dix ans*“ only.

Comment: Ah, perfect. And what if the context were a little different, and *eux* would be inappropriate-- which pronoun would be used to refer to a singular non-person entity, something like "pour {?}"?

Comment: @Aerovistae, in Edouard's example "pour eux" replaces "pour cette agence de voyage", which is a singular non-person entity, and it is fine. It could also replace "pour le gouvernement" or "pour la mafia", or anything.